# Adding Header-Image Slider While Preserving Site Logo and Description

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've downloaded the MetaSlider plugin for WordPress, and am able to insert the generated code into my theme's header.php files so that the slider displays in the correct location. However, the site logo and description disappear when I do this (they should be overlaying the header image). Here's the code for the header.php file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <!-- Preloader -->
    <?php get_template_part( 'templates/header/preloader' ); ?>

    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div id="page-wrap">

        <!-- Boxed Wrapper -->
        <div id="page-header" <?php echo esc_attr(ashe_options( 'general_header_width' )) === 'boxed' ? 'class="boxed-wrapper"': ''; ?>>

        <?php

        // Top Bar
        get_template_part( 'templates/header/top', 'bar' );

        // Page Header
        get_template_part( 'templates/header/page', 'header' );


        // Main Navigation
        get_template_part( 'templates/header/main', 'navigation' );

        ?>

        </div><!-- .boxed-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content">

            <?php get_template_part( 'templates/sidebars/sidebar', 'alt' ); // Sidebar Alt ?>
```

To get the slider into the correct location I need to replace the code underneath //Page Header with the code that Meta Slider provides. The Problem, I think, is that it's replacing the Header Template. So, I've looked at the php for the header template as well, but I'm not sure what, if anything, I might do in there to fix the issue. Here's the header template code:

```
<div class="entry-header">
    <div class="cv-outer">
    <div class="cv-inner">
        <div class="header-logo">

            <?php 

            if ( has_custom_logo() ) :

                $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
                $custom_logo    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );

            ?>

            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr( bloginfo('name') ); ?>" class="logo-img">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url(  $custom_logo[0] ); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr( bloginfo('name') ); ?>">
            </a>

            <?php else : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') ); ?>"><?php echo bloginfo( 'title' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <br>
            <p class="site-description"><?php echo bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas as to how I might go about fixing this would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to give `position:relative; z-index:9999;//z-index number depends`  to your  logo and description?

Comment: I have not! I'm entirely new to WordPress and html/css. Where/how would I implement that?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue but , try to put in your style.css this 2 css   .header-logo{position:relative; z-index:9999;} .site-description{position:relative; z-index:9999;}